# ConnectionString Error webconfig asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have configured IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003, run ASP and HTML well, I have configured a FTP site to update the asp.net via Visual Studio 2010, VStudio makes the publication fine creating these files in the website folder:

```
 Web.config
 Site.Master
 Site1.Master
 Global.asax
 Default.aspx
 About.aspx
 Styles
 Scripts
 bin
 Account
```

When I try to run default.aspx I have this error:

Message Error of Analyser:  Section not recognized : 'connectionStrings'

```
 Line 9:  
 Line 10: <configuration>
 Line 11:   <connectionStrings>
 Line 12:     <add name="ApplicationServices"      
 Line 13:          connectionString="data source= 192.168.1.2;  ;Initial Catalog  =ifdcontroladoria3;uid =sa;pwd = admin2012"
```

this is the code of webconfig

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationServices"      
      connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.2 ;Initial Catalog =ifdcontrol;uid =sa;pwd = evita"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The server 192.168.1.2 or MAQ001 is on the same computer of the IIS 6.0, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to avoid posting user names, catalog names, and passwords in the future. At least the IP listed is local, but still, be careful.

Comment: I have change the real username , database, IP of my real server, but thanks by the recommendation

Answer (score 2):

```
<connectionStrings>  


<add name="ConnectionString" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
 connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1; port=3306; Initial Catalog=*DbName*; 
uid=root; pwd=*password*;"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set ASP.NET version to 2.0 or higher for your application pool. Looks like you are having this problem - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f3df53fe-666b-4a98-92d2-d6e4ba52552a/.